# What query selector can find any array item matching any item from another array?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Is there a mongo query selector allowing me to retrieve every document where, in an array field, at least one item match at least one item from another array?

Let's say I have a mongo document with an array of string in the `reference` field

```
reference: [
    "foo",
    "bar",
    "or",
    "not"
]
```

and I want to select all the documents where I can find an item in the reference array field matching any of the item I have in another array in a javascript variable (let's call it `target`)

```
  var  target= [
        "yes",
        "but",
        "not ",
        "yet"
    ];
```

In this example it would match because `not` is in both arrays.

I know I can do it using `$in` if I look for only one element in a mongo array. However, I would prefer to avoid iterating on my `target` array to look for each item it contains in the `reference` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) combined with `$in` to get the result you desire:

```
find({reference: { $elemMatch: { $in : target } } });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$reference"}, 
  {$match: {reference: {$in: target}}}, 
  {$group: {_id: '$_id', reference: {$push: '$reference'}}}
])
```

The result for your data would be:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("568a82f4f5c54a18bcf843c4"), "reference" : [ "not" ] }
```